# The named parameter 'colors' isn't defined.flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i am using gradient for my custom button when i want to pass gradient color to it, it shows error that says

> The named parameter 'colors' isn't defined.

how can i fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try to restart the Analysis Dart Server.

**Ctrl + Shift + P** on Windows, **Cmd + Shift + P** on Macos opens the command palette if you use VS Code.

Then run **Dart: Restart Analysis Server**.

Answer (score 4):

Clean your project by pressing flutter clean command.

Close the IDE and restart it. And this issue will be solved

Answer (score 1):

You can try restarting the IDE. It will mostly fix the issue.

**Files -> Restart and Invalidate Cache**